ThreadSanitizer reports a data race despite mutex-protected access in pthread_cancel cleanup handler
I am encountering a puzzling issue with ThreadSanitizer while using pthread_cancel and a cleanup handler in a multithreaded C++ program. The sanitizer reports a data race on a global variable even though all accesses to the variable are protected by the same mutex. Below is a minimal reproducible example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mtx_test = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int ga = 0;
void cleanup(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_test);
    ga += 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_test);
    printf("cleanup\n");
}

void* thr_fn(void * arg)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, arg);
    while(true)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_test);
        ga += 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_test);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thr_fn, nullptr);

    sleep(3);
    pthread_cancel(tid);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_test);
    printf("ga: %d\n", ga);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_test);

    pthread_join(tid, nullptr);
}

And here is the output reported by ThreadSanitizer:
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=29924)
  Write of size 4 at 0x5593bd535068 by thread T1:
    #0 cleanup(void*) /tmp/test/test.cpp:10 (a.out+0x139b) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)
    #1 __pthread_cleanup_class::~__pthread_cleanup_class() /usr/include/pthread.h:578 (a.out+0x16c9) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)
    #2 thr_fn(void*) /tmp/test/test.cpp:25 (a.out+0x1493) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)
    #3 thr_fn(void*) /tmp/test/test.cpp:23 (a.out+0x147e) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)

  Previous read of size 4 at 0x5593bd535068 by main thread (mutexes: write M0):
    #0 main /tmp/test/test.cpp:37 (a.out+0x153c) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)

  As if synchronized via sleep:
    #0 sleep ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:383 (libtsan.so.2+0x58691) (BuildId: 38097064631f7912bd33117a9c83d08b42e15571)
    #1 thr_fn(void*) /tmp/test/test.cpp:23 (a.out+0x147e) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)

  Location is global 'ga' of size 4 at 0x5593bd535068 (a.out+0x4068)

  Mutex M0 (0x5593bd535040) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1341 (libtsan.so.2+0x59a13) (BuildId: 38097064631f7912bd33117a9c83d08b42e15571)
    #1 thr_fn(void*) /tmp/test/test.cpp:20 (a.out+0x1438) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)

  Thread T1 (tid=29926, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1022 (libtsan.so.2+0x5ac1a) (BuildId: 38097064631f7912bd33117a9c83d08b42e15571)
    #1 main /tmp/test/test.cpp:31 (a.out+0x14fc) (BuildId: ad9c32e6694e2996bfed96f0eb507bec0278f791)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /tmp/test/test.cpp:10 in cleanup(void*)
==================

The global variable ga is only accessed while holding the mtx_test mutex.
Both in the cleanup handler and in main, the pthread_mutex_lock is explicitly used before accessing ga, ensuring mutual exclusion.
The warning points to a "data race" on ga, but this seems incorrect because the mutex guarantees thread-safe access.
Why does ThreadSanitizer report a data race in this case? Is this a known limitation of ThreadSanitizer when using pthread_cancel and cleanup handlers? If so, how can I address or suppress this false positive? Or is there an actual flaw in my code that I am overlooking?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I would pthread_join directly after pthread_cancel - but - why are you using pthread_cancel instead of using a condition variable? If you cancel the thread while the mutex is locked, the main thread will not be able to acquire it so your program will likely get stuck once every X runs. Also, are you using a very old C++ standard? Why not use std::thread and std::mutex instead of using the platform specific C API pthreads?

@TedLyngmo: In your previous comment, you wrote: "If you cancel the thread while the mutex is locked, the main thread will not be able to acquire it" -- As far as I can tell, there is no such danger. The functions pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock are not on the list of functions that are cancellation points, whereas the function sleep is. Since the thread is in deferred cancellation mode (the default), the only possible cancellation point is the function sleep, which is not being called while the mutex is being held.

@AndreasWenzel Yes, you are correct. I guess one will have to use functions on that list rather than the C++ functions one would normally use in order to ensure they are cancellation points. Instead of std::this_thread::sleep_for one would use clock_nanosleep (even though sleep_for is most probably implemented using clock_nanosleep but it's not specified to do so).

@TedLyngmo I generally agree with your perspective. However, I first want to determine whether the issue is with my code or a false positive from ThreadSanitizer. If the code is correct, reworking it to avoid pthread_cancel would be a significant effort, so I’d prefer a simpler workaround if available. Thank you!

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/646

Summary: sleep interceptor disables nested interceptors, so tsan doesn't realize the mutex is locked when the lock is called from within sleep as it is here.

SIde note, in C++ there should almost be no reason to use the pthread API directly. I would really advice you to use std::jthread, std::mutex, std::scoped_lock/std::unique_lock and reap all the benefits of C++ RAII behavior.

@m.bs "reworking it to avoid pthread_cancel would be a significant effort, so I’d prefer a simpler workaround if available" - Doesn't immediately following pthread_cancel with pthread_join do the trick?

The first rule of pthread_cancel() is never call pthread_cancel().  Preemptive thread cancellation is bad news.  Don't do it. And if you bear that in mind, then you'll never have to face the prospect of reworking a program to avoid relying on pthread_cancel(), because you won't get yourself into that situation in the first place.

As pointed out by someone else in the comments section, there appears to be a bug in ThreadSanitizer that when the function sleep is used as a cancellation point, ThreadSanitizer does not notice the use of thread synchronization during cleanup. Therefore, it appears that the error message reported by ThreadSanitizer is a false positive. As far as I can tell, your code is correct.
As a workaround, you can use __attribute__((no_sanitize("thread"))) on your function cleanup, as described here in the ThreadSanitizer documentation. This will allow your function cleanup to access any variables without triggering an error message from ThreadSanitizer. I have successfully tested this workaround on both GCC and Clang. Alternatively, you can use the suppression or blacklist mechanism.
